# Prove: $\int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx \in (2e^3, 2\sqrt3e^3)$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, definite-integrals

> Prove: $$\int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx \in (2e^3, 2\sqrt3e^3)$$

I would like to know if my proof is ok. The main place I'm afraid it doesn't stick is the fact we need:

$\int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx \in (2e^3, 2\sqrt3e^3)$ and not in $[2e^3, 2\sqrt3e^3]$.

It's easy to calculate: $\int_1^3xe^xdx = 2e^3$.

Now denote:

$$\begin{align*}\int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx &= \int_1^3x\sqrt{x}e^xdx \\&= \int_1^2x\sqrt{x}e^xdx+\int_2^3x\sqrt{x}e^xdx \\&\leq \int_1^2x\sup_{[1,2]}(\sqrt{x})e^xdx+\int_2^3x\sup_{[2,3]}(\sqrt{x})e^xdx \\&= \int_1^2x\sqrt{2}e^xdx+\int_2^3x\sqrt{3}e^xdx \\&\lt \int_1^2x\sqrt{3}e^xdx+\int_2^3x\sqrt{3}e^xdx\\&=\int_1^3x\sqrt{3}e^xdx\end{align*}$$

Thus concluding:

$$\int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx\lt\int_1^3x\sqrt{3}e^xdx$$

In the same manner we can show:

$$\int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx\gt\int_1^3x\sqrt{1}e^xdx=\int_1^3xe^xdx$$

Now notice:

$$2e^3 = \int_1^3xe^xdx \lt \int_1^3\sqrt{x^3}e^xdx \lt \int_1^3x\sqrt{3}e^xdx=2\sqrt{3}e^3$$

As needed.

Comment: Isn’t an open interval weaker than a closed one? Your proof shouldn’t have a problem because in solving for the closed interval bound it automatically includes the open interval bound no?